# Showing the last thursday of the current month with DateJS

Tags: javascript, datejs

I am trying to show the last thursday of the current month with [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/), however this library doesn't really work for me. Could you please help me with the solution?

Comment: Could you make your question more specific? Maybe start with one part of the task that you’re having difficulty with?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [moveToLastDayOfMonth()](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#moveToLastDayOfMonth) method as follows:

```
var lastThuOfThisMonth;

Date.today().moveToLastDayOfMonth().last().is().thursday() ? 
   lastThuOfThisMonth = Date.today().moveToLastDayOfMonth().last() :
   lastThuOfThisMonth = Date.today().moveToLastDayOfMonth().last().thursday();
```

Just tried it in Firebug. I also checked for `last().sunday()` since this month ends with a Sunday.